# Google spreadsheet website form jQuery script block the sending of

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-sheets, google-forms

I have my form in html. I copied action, entry keys and hidden inputs from orginal Google Form.

```
<form id="Gform" role="form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/MY-FORM-KEY/formResponse" method="POST" target="_self" onsubmit="">
                <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-ZążźćśęółbńĄŻŹĆŃŚĘÓŁ ]{4,40}$" name="entry.1028663680" value="" id="entry.1028663680" dir="auto" title="What is Your city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" required>
                <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-ZążźćśęółbńĄŻŹĆŃŚĘÓŁ ]{5,40}$" name="entry.1220908348" value="" id="entry.1220908348" dir="auto" title="Your complete name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
                <input type="tel" name="entry.623688995" value="" id="entry.623688995" dir="auto" title="" class="form-control" placeholder="phone" required>
                <input type="email" name="entry.1564973803" value="" id="entry.1564973803" dir="auto" title="" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="entry.383122401" value="WEBSITE" id="entry.383122401" dir="auto" title="" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[,,&quot;-9139933475238999509&quot;]
">
<input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="-9139933475238999509">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sendData" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

I have te jQuery script, which display confirm:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendContactForm(){
                $("#Gform").fadeOut();
                $("#form-container").append('<p class="confirmer">Thanks!<br>Your email was sent.</p>');
           };
$('#Gform').submit(function () {
 sendContactForm();
 return false;
});
</script>
```

When i delete this script, form is sending, and save to google, but after click submit, I am redirecting to google "Thank You" page. I want to no redirect and display confirm

just like in script. How to fix this problem ?

Comment: You are changing the `MY-FORM-KEY` to your google key, right? What error do you get? Is your form submitted or not? (Press F12 on Google Chrome and watch the *Network* section).

Comment: Is submitted but its look like values of all inputs are empty, but they aren't empty

Comment: Did you check the correct `name="..."` for each `input` in your form with the expected name in Google Forms?

Comment: Yes, all inputs name and id is correct

Comment: @rodrigogq I found javascript which show confirm submit form.

This script look this:
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function sendContactForm(){
                $("#Gform").fadeOut();
                $("#form-container").append('<p class="confirmer">Thank You!<br>Your message was sent!</p>');
           };
$('#bok-form #wyslij').submit(function () {
 sendContactForm();
 return false;
});
</script>

If i comment this script, form is sent, how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add these javascripts/jqueries?

Comment: Ok I changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use AJAX to acomplish your task, when you will use asynchronous function, there won't be reloading page and you will send data behind the scene. In data object enter all input values, in done() and fail() functions define what to do when you recieve response. Good Luck:)

```js
$('#formID').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PrgHQALlz0WrvwjhGpLrtIgD5aQ1x-8HrOubkxTLNKs/formResponse",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
         'entry.111':     $('#entry_111').val(),
         'entry.222': $('#entry_222').val(),
        // all data from form
      }
   }).done(function(data){
      yourAction(data);
   }).fail(function(data){
      failAction(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: Form was sent, but element <p> with confirmation is not shown.

Comment: If you're trying to say that action on .done() wasn't executed so you are right, because after recieving data from this request you will get error containing(redirection issue), that's way put your actions in fail() function. Don't worry, your form will be sended, check it out.

Comment: Ok, it's working now! Yeahh :D Thanks a lot. Everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Comment the `return false` in the code above:

```
$('#Gform').submit(function () {
    sendContactForm();
    //return false;
});
```

Or just delete this line.
What this is script is doing is: subscribing to the `submit` event and canceling it.

Do you want to do something else?

Comment: I just want to send form without redirect to google form confirmation page, and show 'Thank You' in contact form div.

Thanks, I'll delete this line

Comment: Form was sent, but redirect to google page too. How to stop redirection ?

Comment: change form tag `target='self'` to `target='_blank'` or anywhere else. Anyway, you wont get rid from opening another window or redirecting. It won't work on older HTML though.. I can't help more than that, sorry. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp s